# JQuery AutoComplete Combobox "Show All items" haven't been created

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Heloo I am using Jquery autocompete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox, in my MVC project. i am using it for my

```
@Html.DropDownList("examdrp", ViewBag.ExamBag as SelectList, "", new { @id = "combobox" }
```

everything works data loads but i am missing "Show all items" Button

[image]

I tried to do everything same but withought LAYOUT.cshtml and it worked but i need LAYOUT.cshtml on my page!

Answer (score 1):

Ok we can close this thread !! I have done it by myself. IF you are having similar problem you must put jquery files only after botstrap bundles

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>`